# How to obtain the total number of cuts in docplex?

Tags: cplex, docplex

I'm trying to obtain the total number of cuts from a solved docplex model, so basically the sum of the following output:

`Implied bound cuts applied:  7` 
`Flow cuts applied:  10`
`Mixed integer rounding cuts applied:  7`
`Zero-half cuts applied:  2`
`Lift and project cuts applied:  5`
`Gomory fractional cuts applied:  4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet directly provided by docplex, we'll keep this in mind for future versions.
In the meantime you can use this code here:

https://github.com/PhilippeCouronne/docplex_contribs/blob/master/docplex_contribs/src/numcuts.py

Beware this uses non-documented classes and does not check that the model is actually a MIP. Anyway, it returns a dictionary of  cut_name :  number of cuts used, e.g.:

```
 {'cover': 88, 'GUB_cover': 9, 'flow_cover': 6, 'fractional': 5, 'MIR': 9, 'zero_half': 9, 'lift_and_project': 5}
```